# Not able to perform rotation after removing a ContainerUIElement3D from 3D viewport on mousedown event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, helix-3d-toolkit, viewport3d

I can't perform the rotation with the right mouse button on a viewport3d when the mouse is over the `ContainerUIElement3D` that I'm removing during a `PreviewMouserightbuttondown` event. If i click somewhere else outside the element, the rotation will happen and the `ContainerUIElement3D` will be removed and then add on the `ViewPort3d_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp`. 
Here's the code:

```
       Private _modis As ContainerUIElement3D
    Public Property modis() As ContainerUIElement3D
        Get
            Return _modis
        End Get
        Set(value As ContainerUIElement3D)
            _modis = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub ViewPort3d_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)     
        If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
        ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
        ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown Then
        Else
            Dim orvps As Integer = viewPort3d.Children.Count() - 1
            For ii = 0 To orvps
                If viewPort3d.Children(ii).GetType.ToString() = "System.Windows.Media.Media3D.ContainerUIElement3D" Then
                    modis = viewPort3d.Children(ii)
                    viewPort3d.Children.Remove(viewPort3d.Children(ii))
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ViewPort3d_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
        If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
        ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
        ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown Then
        Else
            If modis Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Try
                    viewPort3d.Children.Add(modis)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The main intention is to hide the element during the rotation with the right mouse button, as mentioned before, if i click outside the element, it will rotate and hide the element without issues, if i try to rotate when the mouse is over the element i'm hiding, it will hide the element and add it again after releasing the mouse button but it will not rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is facing this same situation:

I solved this problem, instead of removing and adding back the element, i just set the visibility property to 1 on the PreviewMouserightbuttondown event and set it back to 0 on the PreviewMouseRightButtonUp event.